# How to pass variable from .within() to .then()?

Tags: cypress

I want to pass `foo` from `.within()` to `.then()`. I expected the following code to work, but it doesn't. `foo` ends up being a jQuery element. Is there a way to do this?

```
cy.get('.some-selector')
    .within(() => {
        const foo = 'Some value'
        return foo
    })
    .then((foo) => {
        console.log(foo)
    })
```

Comment: [_"`.within()` yields the same subject it was given from the previous command."_](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within) Could you give an example with more concrete context? In this case you can just make it `.then(() => console.log("Some value"))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypress docs talk about back-flips, which is where an external variable is set by a command callback.

It's warned against, but in this case will work because setting and using are both within sequenced steps.

```js
let foo
cy.get('.some-selector')
  .within(() => {
    foo = 'Some value'
  })
  .then(() => {
    expect(foo).to.eq('Some value')
  })
```